# C# async/await to F# using Azure ML example

Tags: azure, f#, azure-machine-learning-service

I am working with Azure ML and I have the code sample to invoke my web  service (alas it is only in C#).  Can someone help me translate this to F#?  I have everything but the async and await done.

```
 static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                ScoreData scoreData = new ScoreData()
                {
                    FeatureVector = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                    {
                        { "Zip Code", "0" },
                        { "Race", "0" },
                        { "Party", "0" },
                        { "Gender", "0" },
                        { "Age", "0" },
                        { "Voted Ind", "0" },
                    },
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                    {
                    }
                };

                ScoreRequest scoreRequest = new ScoreRequest()
                {
                    Id = "score00001",
                    Instance = scoreData
                };

                const string apiKey = "abc123"; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue( "Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/19a2e623b6a944a3a7f07c74b31c3b6d/services/f51945a42efa42a49f563a59561f5014/score");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW: Looking forward to your next blog post :-) sounds like it will be pretty cool!

Comment: Thanks.  It is now failing on the record to type mapping.  Looking at Fiddler, it says ErrorCode=MissingScoreInstance.  I made sure the cases match.  I wonder if the Json is treating a record and type differently?  It looks like is is postpending an @ symbol?

Comment: That was it.  Changing from a record type to a class made it work.  My blog on Tuesday is going to be fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not able to compile and run the code, but you probably need something like this:

```
let invokeRequestResponseService() = async {
    use client = new HttpClient()
    let scoreData = (...)
    let apiKey = "abc123"
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization <- 
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey)
    client.BaseAddress <- Uri("https://ussouthcentral..../score");
    let! response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest) |> Async.AwaitTask
    if response.IsSuccessStatusCode then
        let! result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode) }
```

- Wrapping the code in the `async { .. }` block makes it asynchronous and lets you use `let!` inside the block to perform asynchronous waiting (i.e. in places where you'd use `await` in C#)
- F# uses type `Async<T>` instead of .NET Task, so when you're awaiting a task, you need to insert `Async.AwaitTask` (or you can write wrappers for the most frequently used operations)
- The `invokeRequestResponseService()` function returns F# async, so if you need to pass it to some other library function (or if it needs to return a task), you can use `Async.StartAsTask`

Comment: We really need a C# to F# converter online.

Comment: That's not entirely possible because C# has features not supported in F#, like protected methods or implicit interface implementation.

Comment: C# -> F# converter would not make any sense. F# is not another C# with a wierd, more succinct syntax.

Comment: any ideas on how to do this without having to wrap the function with async { }

Comment: @DavidCrook What do you mean? The point of `async { .. }` is to let you use asynchronous constructs and make asynchronous calls... So if you want to write asynchronous code, using `async { .. }` is the way to go..